# How to do unit testing with AVA?

Tags: nuxt.js, ava

I'm doing a website booking of coffee-shop for my studies, and I need to do unit test for the front and the back. 
For the front I'm doing test with AVA but I NEVER doing test in my life and I don't know what I need to do. My final examination is Thursday and I need to do fast my units.

Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

```
const test = require("ava");
test.beforeEach(() => { ... })
test.afterEach(() => { ... })
test("Dummy test that passes", t => {
    t.pass()
})
```